# Tianium - Google Maps v2 Shows Blank Screen in android version of titanium

Tags: android, titanium, google-maps-api-2

The Google Maps v2 is showing the following exception

```
  GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your   project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

But i have installed the latest version of play services.

```
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: (TiHttpClient-5) [9594,24182] HTTP Error (java.net.SocketTimeoutException): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:174)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:188)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:178)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:290)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:217)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:637)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1287)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Here are the further details

i had created the API Key using the sha1 key and package name according to documentation

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>

        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <!-- Allows the API to download data from Google Map servers -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <!-- Allows the API to cache data -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <!-- Use GPS for device location -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <!-- Use Wi-Fi or mobile connection for device location -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <!-- Allows the API to access Google web-based services -->
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <!-- Specify OpenGL ES 2.0 as a requirement -->
        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
        <!-- Replace <com.domain.appid> with your application ID -->



         <permission
    android:name="com.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

        <application >

            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="XXXXXXXxxxxXXX"/>
        </application>


    </manifest>
</android>
```

I am using Titanium Studio, build: 3.2.3.201404181442
 and Google map api v2

Comment: are you testing in device or emulator?

Comment: i am testing in device , it has google play services installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution,

I had Just deleted the project the Google Console and Again Started the API key generation From the beginning..

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are using the correct keys from google console.
What Titanium SDK are you using?
What permissions are you setting in the tiapp.xml for the map module?
What android OS are you testing with?
What version of the map module are you working with?